# For each input if they are changed to checked store input ID of checked input in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to store the ID of the input that is currently checked in variable selectedLevelId.

```js
$("[id^=level_]").each(function() {
 $(this).change(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          var selectedLevelId = $(this).prop('id');
          }
});
 });
document.getElementById('levelVal').innerHTML=selectedLevelId;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="level_4432" name="level_id" type="radio" value="4432">
<input id="level_4235" name="level_id" type="radio" value="4235">
<input id="level_1454" name="level_id" type="radio" value="1454">
<input id="level_9823" name="level_id" type="radio" value="9823">

<div id="levelVal">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the output of your logic outside the `.change()` event so JS doesn't know what's happening inside the event. Just put the logic inside and it will work:

```js
var selectedLevelId;

$("[id^=level_]").each(function() {
  $(this).change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      selectedLevelId = $(this).prop('id');
      document.getElementById('levelVal').innerHTML = selectedLevelId;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="level_4432" name="level_id" type="radio" value="4432">
<input id="level_4235" name="level_id" type="radio" value="4235">
<input id="level_1454" name="level_id" type="radio" value="1454">
<input id="level_9823" name="level_id" type="radio" value="9823">

<div id="levelVal">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions

1 -  change it inside the on change event

2 - create an interval that checks for new value every "n" ms

```js
// 1-

/*let selectedLevelId;
$("[id^=level_]").each(function() {
 $(this).change(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            document.getElementById('levelVal').innerHTML = $(this).prop('id');
          }
});
 });
 
*/
// OR

// 2-

let selectedLevelId;
$("[id^=level_]").each(function() {
 $(this).change(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            selectedLevelId = $(this).prop('id');
          }
});
 });
 
 setInterval(function(){
   document.getElementById('levelVal').innerHTML = selectedLevelId;
 }, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="level_4432" name="level_id" type="radio" value="4432">
<input id="level_4235" name="level_id" type="radio" value="4235">
<input id="level_1454" name="level_id" type="radio" value="1454">
<input id="level_9823" name="level_id" type="radio" value="9823">

<div id="levelVal">

</div>
```